# How is the length of a PPP frame known?

Tags: layer2, ppp

How does the receiver determine the length of a PPP frame (not PPPoE or PPPoA)?  [Structure of a PPP frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol#Structure_of_a_PPP_frame) shows no length field.  Sure, at the end of the frame there is a 2-byte checksum followed by a magic byte, but that is hardly collision-proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PPP header starts with a 16-bit protocol id. You need to look at that first in order to know how to interpret the rest.

If the protocol id is LCP/IPCP/IPv6CP then the header structure typically looks like this:

```
struct PPP {
    uint16_t protocolId;
    uint8_t code;
    uint8_t identifier;
    uint16_t length; // <= network-encoded length field
};
```

If the protocol id is IPv4 or IPv6 then the IP header comes immediately after the protocol id. Both IPv4 and IPv6 have a length field in their headers.

I'm not familiar with HDLC frames, but I assume you are receiving them from a socket. The socket read/receive function would provide you with the size of each incoming frame. So you can use that for validation purposes as well.

Comment: As this answer states the inner protocol is identified and that can have a self contained length field. Further to this there is a Flag Sequence which signals the end of the outer PPP header itself: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1662#section-4

Answer (score 4):

> Sure, there is a 2-byte checksum followed by a magic byte, but that is hardly collision-proof.

Occurrences of the magic byte are escaped.  There are two types of escaping used, called "character stuffing" and "bit stuffing".

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957975.aspx